# Insert the next highest value in the database using php

Tags: php, mysqli

Imagine I have a data in the database named `warehouse` and a `whID` for the warehouse number. In my `add.php` I have a form where when you click the submit button, it will add `whID` data higher than the `whID` number in the database without using auto increment. I'ved tried a few code for this but nothing works.

this is my code in `add.php`:

```
<form action="sidenav/function.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="button">Add</button>
</form>
```

This is my code for the function of form in `add.php`:

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO warehouse (whID) VALUES (?)");
$insert->bind_param('i', $whNumber);

if ($insert->execute()) {
header('Location: ../warehouseList.php');
    die();
 }
```

Sorry for my bad English, I hope you understand my question. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you not want to use auto-increment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use auto-increment just get the highest id from database and increment it yourself.

Quick and dirty example:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT MAX(whID) as id FROM warehouse LIMIT 1"); 
$stmt->execute(); 
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$id = $row["id"] + 1;
```

Anyway I recommend you to use auto-increment on the id. That's a scenario for what it's created for.

Comment: Which can lead to 2 separate requests generating the same ID.

Comment: I would recommend to use auto-increment. That's a scenario for what it's created for.